# How to get a new line in command prompt (without executing the former) with a vbs file using Sendkeys?

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt

I'm coding a vbs file to work with command prompt. After the text is printed in cmd, I want to get a new line **without executing** and continue the program with Sendkeys. How to do that? I could't find anywhere.
this is my code upto now

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys"Please wait for a moment.."
wscript.sleep 2000
wshshell.sendkeys "H"
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys "e"
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys "y"
wscript.sleep 90
wshshell.sendkeys "{ }"
wscript.sleep 2000
wshshell.sendkeys "D"
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys "u"
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys "d"
wscript.sleep 200
wshshell.sendkeys "e"
```

Comment: `^` followed by an enter causes the windows command prompt to allow for a new line. I would use `sendkeys` to send the `^` and an Enter and then continue on with your remaining keys.

Comment: but it'll display the text "more?" So it isn't desirable to me..

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do by using SendKeys to a command prompt rather than just running a command yourself?

Comment: Please explain clearly what it is you are trying to achieve, perhaps with example of what you want to see in the cmd window?

Comment: I believe you may have encountered a limitation of the command prompt then. You are interacting with the command prompt as a user since you are using sendkeys, and as such you will run into the "more:" ugliness of the prompt.

Comment: I get the sense that you are pulling a command prompt up, and then building a quick pretty-ish UI for the person to interact with. I think maybe sendkeys and vbscript may not be the best way to do this. Perhaps instead, have vbscript write out a .bat file, then execute that .bat in the command prompt and let the user at it. *Totally guessing here though*

Comment: I didn't get it @JNevill , Sorry I'm still a complete newbie for programming.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Just for fun (if you looked at the code, you could get it)